# Local path doesnt exist

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

```
Caused by: com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
    C:\Program Files\Android\StudioAndroidSDK\sdk\build-tools\21.1.1\dx.bat --dex --verbose --output C:\EclipseWorkspaces\AndroidKepler\MyApp\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\Parse-1.7.1-09008848ab5b3017543589f833cfa07701f139dd.jar C:\EclipseWorkspaces\AndroidKepler\MyApp\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\AndroidKepler\ParseLoginUI\unspecified\libs\Parse-1.7.1.jar
Error Code:
    1
Output:
    The system cannot find the path specified.
```

I just upgraded to Android Studio 1.0.0 and Android SDK updated to 24. My gradle build fails with the above error. Sometimes it show 'Local path doesnt exist'

I've tried doing `<option name="APK_PATH" value="/build/apk/your_app_name-debug-unaligned.apk" />`
and `./gradlew clean packageDebug` but nothing works.

I've tried doing 'Invalidate Cache and Restart', that too doesnt help. Even my JAVA_HOME environment variable is correctly set.
I checked the path where it was looking for apk "MyApp\build\outputs\apk" there is only one file lying there called manifest-merger-debug-report.txt.
I did a *.apk file search on my entire project but didnt find any file.

Please tell me what to do, I'm stuck from 2 days...all work has stopped ...This is so frustrating... :(

Comment: This is what happens when you leave the old way for the new one: you know what you leave, but not what you'll find.

Comment: Have you looked in that manifest merger debug report? What does it say? When you run Gradle, do you see any errors or warnings before the one you posted?

Comment: The merger does not show anything suspicious only talks about the things added or removed.
During build it breaks first time with 'The system cannot find the path specified.' for this command
command: C:\Program Files\Android\StudioAndroidSDK\sdk\build-tools\21.1.1\dx.bat --dex --verbose --output C:\EclipseWorkspaces\AndroidKepler\MyApp\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\Parse-1.7.1-09008848ab5b3017543589f833cfa07701f139dd.jar C:\EclipseWorkspaces\AndroidKepler\MyApp\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\AndroidKepler\ParseLoginUI\unspecified\libs\Parse-1.7.1.jar

Comment: @ScottBarta You are my saviour !!! ..... Thanks a ton ...  :)